# How can I use boost::mpl::fold with a boost::fusion::map?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl, boost-fusion

When I try to compile this:

```
#include <boost/fusion/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    typedef boost::fusion::map
    <
        boost::fusion::pair<int, const char*>,
        boost::fusion::pair<long, char>
    > FuMap;

    FuMap fuMap("hello", 'w');

    unsigned val = boost::mpl::fold
    <
        FuMap, boost::mpl::int_<0>, boost::mpl::next<boost::mpl::_1>
    >::type::value;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
"...boost/mpl/begin_end.hpp", line 35: Error, nofieldfnd: 
apply is not a member of 
boost::mpl::begin_impl<boost::fusion::fusion_sequence_tag>.
```

From the fusion documentation: "Fusion provides full round compatibility 
with MPL. Fusion sequences are fully conforming MPL sequences and MPL 
sequences are fully compatible with Fusion. You can work with Fusion 
sequences on MPL if you wish to work solely on types."

When I pass a boost::mpl::map it works.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question at http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user and the answer from Christopher Schmidt was correct:

```
#include <boost/fusion/mpl.hpp>
```

should fix your problem"

Comment: sorry, the less-than and greater-than erased the include. now it's fixed